# CAN bus delay between sending remote requests

Tags: can-bus

What is the proper way to send multiple remote requests in CAN2.0B/A? Is it usual to have some delay between them like 1/50s, for the receiver to react? I know it shouldnt be needed if proper interrupts are used, i just want to do it the way it is originally designede for.

Answer (score 1):

For future people, no delay is usually needed, be aware an answer can be received while sending remote requests.